# How can I set the index for such database in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have data in a format which has 4 columns - Ticker, Date, LTP, Date_time

1. So first I would like to filter the dataset with Date_time, lets say at 10:00 AM
2. It would give me number of rows as Ticker and LTP would be different
3. I would sort them in LTP in descending order
4. I would choose the top most Ticker
5. Filter the complete dataset with this Ticker on the current date

So In a way I want to filter the dataset with all the 4 columns. So should I make all the 4 columns as index ?

I ran this to create an index

```
cursor.execute('CREATE INDEX combined ON options(Ticker,LTP,Date_time)')

import time
start_time = time.time()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM options WHERE Ticker = 'BANKNIFTY06JAN2230500PE.NFO' AND LTP > 1 AND Date_time = '2021-12-31 09:18:18'")
results = cursor.fetchall()
end_time = time.time()
print('Time taken :',end_time-start_time)
```

When I am making only Date_time as index, it is fast but when I am making all the 3 columns as index, the search query is not that fast as should be

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Have you actually run the query to see if you have an issue that needs resolving? If there is an issue then see @FrankHeikens comment.